# c++ will compiler optimize argument by value to argument by rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue

I think to recall that someone told me that these two methods

```
foo(std::vector<int>&& v) {
  member = std::move(v);
}

bar(std::vector<int> v) {
  member = std::move(v);
}
```

both will not invoke a copy if there is a move at the call site

```
foo(std::move(v1));
bar(std::move(v2));
```

since the compiler will optimize the call and treat the `bar` case as if it would take the argument by rvalue reference and therefore one should favor the `bar` syntax since it's less convoluted and can also be called with an lvalue (in which case of course a copy will be made).

Is this true? can one rely on the `bar`case not creating a copy so long as one calls it with an rvalue?

Comment: You can do both. Often people argue for the second case, but this might involve an extra move when it is otherwise not needed

Comment: A relevant note for this question is that `std::vector` has a move constructor, and it is efficient.  A different type may not.

Comment: @DrewDormann oooh so that's what's happening. The value argument is being constructed via its move constructor and that's why there is no copy being created so long as the function is called with an rvalue?

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann Yes!  That makes `bar` a good choice for both l-values and r-values.  Your `foo` only accepts r-values.

Comment: If the intention is to always move out the argument, the first version is safer as it won't bind to mutable lvalue references and make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

> can one rely on the `bar` case not creating a copy so long as one calls it with an rvalue?

No, not necessarily.
An example in which a copy will take place:

```
const std::vector<int> vec;

bar( std::move(vec) );
```

Here `std::move` will cast `vec` (an **lvalue**) to an **xvalue** (i.e. **rvalue**). But it won't be moved since `vec` is *constant* and can not be modified. Thus the **move constructor** of `std::vector` won't be called.

Now I tried your code with a bit of modification in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hP76h44eK) and I got the results that you expected.

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

void foo( std::vector<int>&& v )
{
    auto member = std::move(v);
}

void bar( std::vector<int> v )
{
    auto member = std::move(v);
}


int main( )
{
    std::vector<int> v1(3, 1000);
    std::vector<int> v2(3, 2000);

    //foo( std::move(v1) ); // uncomment this
    //bar( std::move(v2) ); // uncomment this
    bar( v2 );              // and comment this out

    for ( const auto& num : v1 )
    {
        std::cout << num << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( const auto& num : v2 )
    {
        std::cout << num << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

First, you will see the output as:

```
1000 1000 1000 
2000 2000 2000
```

But then do the things I mentioned above and you will see that the output will disappear. This is because after *moving the two vectors*, they will become empty due to losing ownership of their buffer. So the for-loops will print nothing. This really proves that a move is happening in `bar( std::move(v2) );`. And `bar( v2 );` is a deep copy.

Comment: The fault would lie with the caller though in this case, since `std::move` on a `const` object doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: LEA means it loads the address though rather than the value (MOV), no?

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann This is what GCC v11.2 generates with -O3 enabled. I think it's a call to the copy constructor. Otherwise we would see `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&` for lvalue references or `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&&` for rvalue references.

Comment: `bar( std::move(v2) )` does 2 moves (no copies). The parameter is move-constructed from the argument

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann **LEA** is short for `load effective address`. And speaking of `mov` instruction in x86-64 ISA, it does not necessarily correspond to `std::move` of C++. `std::move` is just a simple cast to rvalue. It is equivalent to `static_cast<T&&>(t)`. But they might be relatable in this case.

Comment: @M.M Is there any valid way to know this? I mean how can one know that a move happened and not a copy?

Comment: @digito_evo by understanding the language standard,  you can read the standard and/or read other highly upvoted answers on the subject

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann I updated the answer. Check it out!